# Keep watchOS data up to date

Tags: ios, swift, session, watchkit, background-process

I'm writing an independent app for Apple Watch. The structure is the following:
`class HostingController` calls `class ContentView`,
`class ContentView` has an instance of `EventFetcher` declared as 
`@ObservedObject var ef: EventFetcher = EventFetcher()`. 
Below the class EventFecthcer

```
public class EventFetcher: ObservableObject{

@Published var eventi = [EventoWK]()


 init(){
    load()
}

func load() {
  ---decoding items from JSON
}
```

}

Data are decoded and loaded right in my list. I want to reload the list making a background request. I follow the steps indicated in the documentation here [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/keeping_your_watchos_content_up_to_date/making_background_requests).
This is my code to make the background request in the class ExtensionDelegate:

```
import WatchKit

class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate, URLSessionDelegate {
func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
    // Perform any final initialization of your application.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive() {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillResignActive() {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, etc.
}

func handle(_ backgroundTasks: Set<WKRefreshBackgroundTask>) {
    // Sent when the system needs to launch the application in the background to process tasks. Tasks arrive in a set, so loop through and process each one.
    for task in backgroundTasks {
        // Use a switch statement to check the task type
        switch task {
        case let backgroundTask as WKApplicationRefreshBackgroundTask:
            // Be sure to complete the background task once you’re done.
            backgroundTask.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)
        case let snapshotTask as WKSnapshotRefreshBackgroundTask:
            // Snapshot tasks have a unique completion call, make sure to set your expiration date
            snapshotTask.setTaskCompleted(restoredDefaultState: true, estimatedSnapshotExpiration: Date.distantFuture, userInfo: nil)
        case let connectivityTask as WKWatchConnectivityRefreshBackgroundTask:
            // Be sure to complete the connectivity task once you’re done.
            connectivityTask.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)
        case let urlSessionTask as WKURLSessionRefreshBackgroundTask:
            // Be sure to complete the URL session task once you’re done.
            urlSessionTask.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)
        case let relevantShortcutTask as WKRelevantShortcutRefreshBackgroundTask:
            // Be sure to complete the relevant-shortcut task once you're done.
            relevantShortcutTask.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)
        case let intentDidRunTask as WKIntentDidRunRefreshBackgroundTask:
            // Be sure to complete the intent-did-run task once you're done.
            intentDidRunTask.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)
        default:
            // make sure to complete unhandled task types
            task.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)
        }
    }
}



    func loadInBackground(){


          let url = URL(string: "https://myserver/mypath/myfile.json")!
           let backgroundSessionConfig : URLSessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "it.myserver.bgt")
           let bgsession: URLSession = URLSession(configuration: backgroundSessionConfig,delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

        let task = bgsession.downloadTask(with: url) { localURL, urlResponse, error in
            if let localURL = localURL {
                if let string = try? String(contentsOf: localURL) {
                    print(string)
                }
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }// loadInBackground
```

}

Apple documentation point 5 and 6 of the previous link indicate "Implement your WatchKit extension delegate’s handle(_:) method to respond to (and complete) the WatchKit background task." But putting the call of my method  loadInBackground in the handle method it doesn't work.
And then they suggest to implement " the session delegate’s methods to receive data ".
I wonder how to implement this background session to make my request and update my data for the user.
I did in my code the steps 1 to 4 but how and when should the method loadInBackground() be called to update the list?
Thanks, any help understanding the session mechanism is appreciated.

Comment: You should only have one instance of your data model (`EventFetcher`) in your app.  When you get the `WKApplicationRefreshBackgroundTask` you trigger a load to update that instance and call `connectivityTask.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)` in a completion handler that you pass to your load method

Comment: So, I have the instance of EventiFetcher declared in the class ContentView. In var body of this class I read the list and display the items. I wonder how to implement the mechanism explained. I'll try to implement your advice but it's not clear for me because I'm not an expert of this kind of stuff. Thank you Paulw11.

Comment: One way is make your `EventFetcher` a property of your `ExtensionDelegate`.  Then you can get this property using `WKExtension.shared().delegate` in your view hosting controller.

Comment: I moved my var `@ObservedObject var ef: EventoFetcher = EventoFetcher() ` in the `class ExtensionDelegate` and the code in hosting controller is this:   `override var body: ContentView {
        
        var delegate = WKExtension.shared().delegate
        var ef: EventoFetcher = delegate.
        
        return ContentView(ef: ef)
    }    `                                                                                         the problem is I can't get the EventFetcher property using the delegate. However thank you @Paulw11